# Using HTML in bootstrap typeahead - how to cleanup html for text input box

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I need to use HTML in a bootstrap typeahead box, to allow me to indent items.

To get something like this:

> Top-Level-Item
>      Indented item
>   Next Item (Unindented)

I accomplish this by putting HTML in my typeahead data-source like so:

```
var ajaxData = {json: JSON.stringify(["Top-Level-Item<br />&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;Indented Item","Next Item (Unindented)"])};
```

This works fine in the typeahead 'drop-down-style' box you get, however when clicking a result which contains HTML, the result with the readable HTML tags is put into the text input element.

See below a JSFiddle which shows what I mean (start to type 'Alabama' to see the result with HTML in it): http://jsfiddle.net/mc0oocj4/

What is the best way to solve this? I was thinking about cleaning up the HTML before updating the textbox, but I have no idea how to accomplish this (the updating of the textbox happens by bootstraps internal kitchen, which I'd rather not mess with...)

Off source other/better ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
$('.typeahead').on('change', function (e) {
     this.value = this.value.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '').replace(/&nbsp;/gm,'');
});
```

Working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/mc0oocj4/3/

Comment: Thanks! I actually though of this, but I assumed the `.on('change')` code would also be triggered when typing normally in the textbox and mess up the user input, off course now I see this is only true if the user would type HTML into the box, in which case it would actually be a good thing.

Comment: Did you see that when typing a character of your html code (like n in nbsp) the html text in the dropdown?